# The spans that make up my hamburger menu icon have the wrong heights

Tags: javascript, html, css, hamburger-menu

My hamburger menu icon is three spans in a flex display. I'm trying to implement an animation for the icon to change when the menu is opened. However, the height of the spans seems to be different despite the applied class being the same. To encounter this problem just resize the screen until the heights become different. I have tried various solutions but nothing seems to work. I am attaching my code:

```css
#header__iconaMenu {
  height: 1.5rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: .3rem;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
}

.iconaMenu__line {
  width: 100%;
  height: .13rem;
  background-color: var(--disabledTxtColor);
  border-radius: 1.5rem;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<header id="header">
  <nav id="header__menu">
    <a id="home" class="active" onclick="goTo(id)">Chi sono</a>
    <a id="portfolio" onclick="goTo(id)">Portfolio</a>
    <a id="social" onclick="goTo(id)">Social</a>
    <a id="contatti" onclick="goTo(id)">Contatti</a>
  </nav>
  <div id="header__spaceIconaMenu">
    <div id="header__iconaMenu" class="small" onclick="toggleMenu()">
      <span class="iconaMenu__line topLine"></span>
      <span class="iconaMenu__line midLine"></span>
      <span class="iconaMenu__line endLine"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I couldn't reproduce the issue using your code snippet

Comment: the snippet was unfortunately not added by me. I'm not sure how to get you to test the problem, even as long as you should be able to change screen size. I hope you can come to a conclusion with just the description of the facts